Print event listeners onafterprint and onbeforeprint work normally but not inside onload
The following code should print a PDF by

opening it in a popup window,
starting the print dialogue window and
closing the popup as soon as the print window is closed.

It works as expected in Chrome (but not in Firefox - not important at the moment):
var myWindow=window.open(pdfUrl,'','width=600,height=600');
myWindow.print();
myWindow.close();

The problem is that I need the pdf link to load before the print() is initiated; otherwise, I am printing a blank page. This leads to the following problem:

when I put myWindow.print();myWindow.close(); inside onload definition, myWindow.close() closes immediately and does not wait for myWindow.print()
eventlisteners do not work either inside onload

    var myWindow=window.open(pdfUrl,'','width=600,height=600');
    myWindow.onload = function() {
        myWindow.onafterprint = () => {
        myWindow.close();
        }
        myWindow.onbeforeprint = () => {
        ...
        }
        myWindow.print();
        //myWindow.close(); <- closes immediately without waiting no matter what I do
    };

I have tried every suggestion from this and this answers, NOTHING WORKS.

If you put console.log("In afterprint") in the event listener, does that work? There are some restrictions on how Window.close() can be used, you may be running into it.
